# HikariCP number of connections in multiple pools

Tags: mysql, clojure, database-connection, hikaricp

I'm using HikariCP in a Clojure app via the hikari-cp Clojure library.

The app serves multiple clients that all have their own MySQL database and database user. Each client has their own HikariCP connection pool, from my understanding this is required since each client has a dedicated database user. After adding a new client, I started getting intermittent "Too many connections" errors from MySQL. I guess that the default pool size of 10 connections per client adds up to too many connections (more than the max_connections default setting of 151 in MySQL).

The overall/per client database load is not very large.

Simply reducing the number of connections per client seems cumbersome since the pool size would then have to be reduced whenever new clients are added.

Would it be safe to simply set max_connections to a number proportional to the number of clients, say 50 + [number of clients] * 10?

Or is there a way to use the same pool to connect to different databases (with different db users)?

Comment: Have you tried running w/o db pooling at all?  If you many many (client X DB) combinations, that is by far the most bulletproof, and establishing a connection is pretty fast normally.

Comment: Actually no. I just based the app on the default setup in Clojure's Luminus web framework, which includes hikari-cp. You mean that a new connection would be made to the database on each request to the app?

Comment: Yes, that is by far the simplest and usually fast enough (esp since there is no clear way to pool all of your possible combinations).

Comment: Interesting. I have very little know-how when it comes to database performance and connection handling so I just assumed that connection pooling was the way to go since it's the default in Luminus. There is however a 1-1 correspondence between a client and a database - each client has 1 database and 1 dedicated db user that is used when connecting to that client's database (sorry if that was unclear). But perhaps your reasoning applies anyway?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](https://github.com/cloojure/demo-jdbc/blob/master/src/tst/demo/jdbc.clj) test file that doesn't use connection pooling.  You can either create a new DB connection for a single command, for a group of commands, or for each transaction:

```
(def raw-db-spec
  {:classname   "org.h2.Driver"
   :subprotocol "h2:mem"    ; the prefix `jdbc:` is added automatically
   :subname     "demo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1" ; `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` very important!!!
                     ; http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases
                     ; http://makble.com/using-h2-in-memory-database-in-clojure
   :user        "sa"        ; "system admin"
   :password    ""          ; empty string by default
   })

(dotest
  ; creates & drops a connection (& transaction) for each command
  (jdbc/db-do-commands raw-db-spec ["drop table if exists langs"
                                    "drop table if exists releases"])

  ; Creates and uses a connection for all commands
  (jdbc/with-db-connection
    [conn raw-db-spec]
    (jdbc/db-do-commands
      conn
      [(jdbc/create-table-ddl :langs
                              [[:id :serial]
                               [:lang "varchar not null"]])
       (jdbc/create-table-ddl :releases
                              [[:id :serial]
                               [:desc "varchar not null"]
                               [:langId "numeric"]])]))

  ; create & use a connection for multiple commands
  (jdbc/with-db-connection
    [conn raw-db-spec]
    (jdbc/insert-multi! raw-db-spec :langs ; => ({:id 1} {:id 2})
                        [{:lang "Clojure"}
                         {:lang "Java"}])

    (let [result (jdbc/query raw-db-spec ["select * from langs"])]
      (is= result [{:id 1, :lang "Clojure"}
                   {:id 2, :lang "Java"}])))

  ; Wraps all commands in a single transaction
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction
    [tx raw-db-spec]
    (let [clj-id (grab :id (only (jdbc/query tx ["select id from langs where lang='Clojure'"])))]
      (jdbc/insert-multi! tx :releases
                          [{:desc "ancients" :langId clj-id}
                           {:desc "1.8" :langId clj-id}
                           {:desc "1.9" :langId clj-id}]))
    (let [java-id (grab :id (only (jdbc/query tx ["select id from langs where lang='Java'"])))]
      (jdbc/insert-multi! tx :releases
                          [{:desc "dusty" :langId java-id}
                           {:desc "8" :langId java-id}
                           {:desc "9" :langId java-id}
                           {:desc "10" :langId java-id}])))
```

[Here is a different file](https://github.com/cloojure/demo-jdbc/blob/master/src/tst/demo/jdbc_pool.clj) showing the use of Hikari DB pooling.

```
(def datasource-options-sample {:auto-commit        true
                                :read-only          false
                                :connection-timeout 30000
                                :validation-timeout 5000
                                :idle-timeout       600000
                                :max-lifetime       1800000
                                :minimum-idle       10
                                :maximum-pool-size  10
                                :pool-name          "db-pool"
                                :adapter            "h2" ; "postgresql"
                                :username           "sa"
                                :password           ""
                                :database-name      "database"
                                :server-name        "localhost"
                                :port-number        5432
                                :register-mbeans    false})

(def datasource-options {:adapter  "h2"
                         :url      "jdbc:h2:mem:demo;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
                         :username "sa"
                         :password ""})

(def ^:dynamic db-conn nil)

(defn with-connection-pool
  "Creates and uses a connection for test function"
  [tst-fn]
  (let [datasource (pool/make-datasource datasource-options)]
    (binding [db-conn {:datasource datasource}]
      (tst-fn)
      (pool/close-datasource datasource)))) ; close the connection - also closes/destroys the in-memory database

(use-fixtures
  :once with-connection-pool) ; use the same db connection pool for all tests

(dotest
  ; creates & drops a connection (& transaction) for each command
  (jdbc/db-do-commands db-conn ["drop table if exists langs"
                                "drop table if exists releases"])

  (jdbc/db-do-commands
    db-conn
    [(jdbc/create-table-ddl :langs
                            [[:id :serial]
                             [:lang "varchar not null"]])
     (jdbc/create-table-ddl :releases
                            [[:id :serial]
                             [:desc "varchar not null"]

                             [:langId "numeric"]])])
  (jdbc/insert-multi! db-conn :langs ; => ({:id 1} {:id 2})
                      [{:lang "Clojure"}
                       {:lang "Java"}])
  (let [result (jdbc/query db-conn ["select * from langs"])]
    (is= result [{:id 1, :lang "Clojure"}
                 {:id 2, :lang "Java"}]))
```

I would suggest making a fork of your project and deleting all of the connection pooling stuff and try running it.  You can use (jdbc/with-db-connection ...)`or`(jdbc/with-db-connection ...)` to group multiple commands into a single DB connection if you want to add that later.

Comment: Thanks! I also use conman to bind hugsql queries to the hikari-cp connection. I guess that abandoning hikari-cp would require some major rewrite to keep the hugsql bindings?

Comment: Ok. Perhaps if I were to only use 1 connection per pool - I could keep conman/hugsql and basically just maintain one static connection for each client. That would hardly exhaust the max_connections settings. But then I guess that HikariCP would block when multiple requests are made to the same client db? (I realize that I'm then using HikariCP to solve another problem [keeping conman / hugsql]).